# line.split() list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently encountering this error for the next code: `chain['xxx']=line.split()[10] IndexError: list index out of range`

```
import xlsxwriter

word='Chain'

def create_chain(chain_segment):
    chains=[]
    chain_lines = [line for line in chain_segment.split('\n') if line]
    for line in chain_lines:
        chain={}
        if word in line:
            chain['type'] = line.split()[1]
        elif line[0].isdigit():
            chain['num']=line[0]
            chain['pkts']=line.split()[1]
            chain['bytes']=line.split()[2]
            chain['target']=line.split()[3]
            chain['prot']=line.split()[4]
            chain['opt']=line.split()[5]
            chain['in']=line.split()[6]
            chain['out']=line.split()[7]
            chain['source']=line.split()[8]
            chain['destination']=line.split()[9]
            chain['xxx']=line.split()[10]
        chains.append(chain)
        chains=filter(None, chains)
    chains=list(chains)
    chained = [merge_dicts(chains[0], i) for i in chains[1:]]
    return chained

def merge_dicts(x,y):
   z=x.copy()
   z.update(y)
   return z

with open('/media/sf_vboxshared/iptables-list.log') as f:
    log_content = f.read()

host_sections = [host for host in log_content.split('---') if host]
hosts = {}

for host in host_sections:
    hostname, chains_segment = host.split('\n', 1)
    hostname = hostname.strip()
    chains=[]
    for segment in chains_segment.split('\n\n'):
            chains.extend(create_chain(segment))
    hosts[hostname] = chains

workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('/media/sf_vboxshared/iptables-1st.xlsx')
worksheet1=workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

worksheet1.write(0,0,'hostname')
worksheet1.write(0,1,'chain')
worksheet1.write(0,2,'num')
worksheet1.write(0,3,'pkts')
worksheet1.write(0,4,'bytes')
worksheet1.write(0,5,'target')
worksheet1.write(0,6,'prot')
worksheet1.write(0,7,'opt')
worksheet1.write(0,8,'in')
worksheet1.write(0,9,'out')
worksheet1.write(0,10,'source')
worksheet1.write(0,11,'destination')
row = 1

for host, chains in hosts.items():
    for chain in chains:
        worksheet1.write(row, 1, chain.get('type'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 0, host)
        worksheet1.write(row, 2, chain.get('num'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 3, chain.get('pkts'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 4, chain.get('bytes'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 5, chain.get('target'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 6, chain.get('prot'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 7, chain.get('opt'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 8, chain.get('in'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 9, chain.get('out'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 10, chain.get('source'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 11, chain.get('destination'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 12, chain.get('xxx'))
        row += 1

workbook.close()
```

In the input, for the last column, some of the rows don't have a value. For sure, that error is caused by these empty spaces because I've filled them with something random and it worked perfectly. I would need to make the code somehow to ignore if there are empty spaces.

The input is very large, but this is the pattern of the file.

```
---node1
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        1     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
2       25  16K  ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
3        7   28  ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
4       58  39K  ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
5      81K  25M  ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 398 packets, 23K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     2K      3M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Is any way to achieve this? 
P.S. I am using Python 2.7

Many thanks in advance,

Romain

Comment: What is the content of `line` when `line.split()[10]` raises the error?

Comment: `line.split()[10]` fails if there aren't enough tokens to split. e.g. an empty line :)

Comment: @khelwood: Thanks for your reply. Here is the printout of the line before line.split()[10]: `1        1     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1stiptables.py", line 47, in <module>
    chains.extend(create_chain(segment))
  File "1stiptables.py", line 24, in create_chain
    chain['xxx']=line.split()[10]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks for your reply and I totally agree that this is the reason, but is any way to fix this?

Comment: yep. Split and control the number of elements that split returns. Take the 11th one only if the len of the list is long enough.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks a lot for your solution and should work, but I would prefer offeltoffel's.

Comment: no prob. it was just a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the input, for the last column, some of the rows don't have a
>   value. For sure, that error is caused by these empty spaces because
>   I've filled them with something random and it worked perfectly. I
>   would need to make the code somehow to ignore if there are empty
>   spaces.

You will understand that python cannot tell you the value of index 10 if there is no such index. In other words: You are at a restaurant and usually eat a five-course menu. The waiter only gives you four and later asks you how you liked the fifth. There is no answer to that question.

The most pythonic way to handle that problem would be to `try` and `except`:

```
# [...]
chain['source']=line.split()[8]
chain['destination']=line.split()[9]
try:
    chain['xxx']=line.split()[10]
except IndexError:
    pass # or do something else
```

In fact, the above solution is considered better than checking the length of `line` and disallowing to proceed to item [10] if there aren't enough.

Comment: `except IndexError` please

Comment: @offeltoffel: Thanks a lot for your reply. It works good, it ignores the empty spaces. The only thing is that the script is taking just one word from that last column. I have tried `chain['xxx']=line.split()[10:]`, but I get an error. Is any way to take all words until the end of the line? Many thanks.

Comment: `chain['xxx']=line.split()[10:]` should give you all splits from 10 to the end. What does the error say?
@bobrobbob: thanks, I updated accordingly.

Comment: @offeltoffel: Here is the error:    `raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))
TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'list'> in write()
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x7fba2c910090>> ignored`

Comment: @offeltoffel: It seems that, for example, `chain['xxx']=line.split()[10]+" "+line.split()[11]` works, but I would need to have it in a more Pythonic way, if is possible

Comment: looks like it's a problem of how you read the workbook. I have never used xlsxwriter, sorry.